# Bootstrap navigation not working with Angular ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am getting an error while displaying dynamic navigation in Angular Bootstrap using ng-repeat. The collapse nav is not working.

My code is:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="menu in menus.menus">
     <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span class="menu-item-parent">{{menu.name}}</span>
     </a>
     <ul class="sub-left-nav" >
        <li ng-repeat="submenu in menu.submenu">
           <a href="#/{{submenu.url}}" target="open_frame">{{submenu.name}}</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.menus = {
    "menus": [
        {
            "name": "Master Maintenance",
            "submenu": [
                {
                    "name": "CropType",
                    "url": "croptype"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CropMaster",
                    "url": "crop"
                }
            ]
        }
     ]
}
```

When I do not use ng-repeat and json and use only static nav, all things works fine.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Dashboard"><span class="menu-item-parent">Link 1</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="menu-item-parent">Link 2</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-left-nav">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="open_frame">Sub Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="open_frame">Sub Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="open_frame">Sub Link 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Any console error of Angular JS u r getting ?

Comment: Can you provide fiddle?

Comment: there is no console error of Angular JS. It is fetching the menus and showing but the expand-collapse thing is not working

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

The question was not clear and made me think of a typo mistake... Please see the comment.

Comment: I checked it. by mistake i kept wrong code here. i edited it. It is fetching the menus and showing but the expand-collapse thing is not working with ng-repeat

Comment: Sorry, what did you mean by expand-collapse thing?

Comment: please check this link
http://192.241.236.31/themes/preview/smartadmin/1.4.1/ajaxversion/#ajax/dashboard.html
here you will see whenever a menu is clicked it submenus are shown and other with will get hidden.

Comment: Well, I have a look and to tell the truth. I couldn't get what you wanted to ask by just reading your questions and comments...

I supposed you wanted to ask why the Nav output by using ng-repeat didn't have the expand-collapse behaviour. It could be because of a lot of things I saw in your website link. I don't think it's a good idea to use plain jQuery plugins with AngularJS, better be wrapped in some directives.
If you can create a Plunker of just the Nav then I might be able to help.